# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'charss'

Tags: python, list, class, dictionary

I am new to OOP with python. I have 3 classes with one being called from the other as a parameter instance:

```
class Characters:
    def __init__(self, b="", c = ""):
        self.b= b
        self.c= c           

class Words:
    def __init__(self, charss=Characters()):       
        self.charss= charss

class Sentences:
    def __init__(self, w=Words()):
        self.w = w
```

I am then creating a new instance of class Words form another Class and filling it with data i have from a json file.

```
s = Sentences()
s.__dict__ = json.loads(output.content)
```

When debugging i can see that `s` is populated correctly. I am then trying to print out the values of `s` like this:

```
print(s.w[0].charss[0])
```

an error occurs:`AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'charss'`

is it because I am populating from the `JSON` as `__dict__` where `charss` instantiated as `list`. If that is so what would be the best solution changing the `__dict__` from `json` input or instantiating the object as `__dict__`?

Comment: Beware of using [mutable default arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

Comment: @glibdud how is that the issue?

Comment: It's not, that's just a public service announcement.

Comment: @glibdud ok Thank you for that. Do you happen to know what my issue is though?

Comment: What is the content of `output.content`?

Comment: output is a requests.get(url) which contains a json formatted string

Comment: Can you paste the actual contents into the question (redacted as necessary)?

Comment: You wrote "`word` is populated correctly", but there's no symbol called `word` in any of your code. Do you mean `s`?

Comment: yes i will edit that i mean s

Comment: @glibdud there is no need to post it here it is a long unuseful String that contains data in a json format. it is then being converted into python objects with json.loads function

Comment: Well then we can't tell you what's wrong, because after you set `s.__dict__` to that, `s`'s attributes are entirely defined by what's in there.

Comment: ... interesting question... I want to see this solved somehow. cheers for the service anouncement... > learned something very valuable today about something I thought was indeed a glitch in py2.7 and predecessors (might have solved in 3.5, which as I understand now shouldn't!) < (no need for down-voting Bruno Desthuilliers... it shows you are not able to see the beauty yet.. you will).

Comment: I wouldn't even worry about the error just yet, because it's not clear how you even intend to use the classes as designed. What is `Characters` supposed to represent--what are `b` and `c`? What is `Words` if not just a wrapper around a single `Characters` instance (and the same question applies to `Sentences`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way the instance `s` is being accessed for printing. I am saving the json output as a dictionary but the instance of a class is by default a list. therefore instead of

```
print(s.w[0].charss[0])
```

that line should be

```
print(s.w[0]["charss"][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say `s.__dict__ = some_dictionary`, you're entirely replacing all the instance variables of `s` with the ones in `some_dictionary`. This includes `w`, which is now defined entirely by whatever's in your JSON. JSON objects are never going to have `charss` attributes, so it's guaranteed to fail in the way you mention.

What are you trying to accomplish with `s.__dict__ = json.loads(output.content)`? Do you just want to store the dictionary in `s`? If so, `s.my_cool_dict_name = json.loads(output.content)` might be what you want.

Comment: with s.__dict__ = json.loads(output.content) i want to pupulate instance s and whatever sub instances is creates when called. this can be done because the json i am reading from has also the same structure of the class s and sub classes w and charss

Comment: No, it can't – JSON objects will never be converted python objects with arbitrary attributes, only strings, ints, lists, and dicts, and thus will never have a `charss` attribute. If it is actually a dictionary, then you need ['charss'] instead of .chars.

Comment: Yes i realised that after sometime in fact that was the answer I was looking for  but I managed to find the answer myself. thanks anyways.